# Traversing to find a vertex in node and returns index

Tags: c++, tree, depth-first-search

I'm working with tree decomposition and I'm trying **to find a vertex in the tree nodes**.

I want to **return the index of that node** if vertex is found. I'm trying to traverse the tree in a DFS manner. I was able to traverse all the nodes, but once the node with vertex is found its not returning the index.

Below is what i tried. Can someone point out where am i going wrong?

```
Node* Tree::traversing(Node* node, int v) {

    vector<Node*> s;
    s.push_back(node);  

    while(!s.empty()) {

        Node* nn = s.back();
        s.pop_back();
        int i = nn->point_in_bag(v);
        if(i != -1) { return nn;}

        for(int i=0; i<node->children.size(); i++) {
            Node* n = node->children[i];
            s.push_back(n); 
        }

    }
}
```

The function `point_in_bag` returns positive integer if found and `-1` if vertex not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!! You just need to change the code:

```
for(int i=0; i<node->children.size(); i++)
```

to:

```
for(int i=0; i< nn->children.size(); i++)
```

and also in the body. Do you know why?

Comment: Because when you traverse the whole tree, the current node always changes, so you can't only use the persistent pointer node to get the current node's children node.